# MS Access linked table slow to aknowledge new records

Tags: ms-access

I have a linked table `tblLinked` which has new records coming in every 0.5 secs or so. I have a form `frmLinked` whose recordsource is `tblLinked`. When I requery `frmLinked`, I notice (from a `timestamp` field in `frmLinked`) that new records which have been added to `tblLinked` in the last 5 secs or so do not appear on the form. If I keep requerying, these records appear 5 secs later.

This lag did not happen prior to splitting the database. So why does Access only check for new records in linked records every 5 secs? How can I reduce this lag interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open connections to Access database files that are not local (i.e., not a table in the same .accdb/.mdb as the Access form) tend to have a "refresh rate" of approximately 5 seconds. This seems to be a function of the ACE/Jet database engine. My other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063542/2144390) refers to OLEDB connections, but it could very well apply to DAO connections as well.

Comment: Thanks. So any ideas as to a solution? Should I just keep opening and closing the `DAO.recordset` object of the linked table as your post on OLEDB would suggest?