# Access DB not updating quick enough though ODBC connection and Mitel call flow

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc, telephony, vba

I have a 2010 MS Access database that is being updated from an excel VB form to hold vehicle details. That's the easy bit and all the VB works fine and the database is updating.
The difficult bit comes when I created a telephony IVR call flow in your site explorer (Mitel). This reads the database every 30 seconds to see if there has been any new records entered, if there has then it marks the database record as 'call in progress' and sets the time to the next call as 5 minutes time. Again, this all works fine UNTIL I add more than 1 port to the call flow.
I am now in the situation that the first port will call out and update the database, but another port will access the same record before the first port updates the database and so calls the same destination about the same job. 
I've tried changing the refresh rates within access to 1 sec, but no success.
I realise this is all a bit complicated, but it's basically a problem with access not updating quickly enough (i.e. it needs to update within a second). Any help would be gratefully accepted, as this is now totally doing my head in.

The database is saved as a mdb and not accdb, if this makes any difference.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please post some code so we can try to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Excel vba code to insert data into the access table:

Comment: Edit your question to include your code.  You can't put it in comments.

Comment: Try closing the connection immediately after performing the update to flush the change back to the database. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17063542/2144390) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Answer turned out to be, open and close the database in the vb code after inserting data into the database table via an ODBC link. This automatically updates the database table with the record just added. The outbound telephony ports didn't then try to call twice (or more) for the same record, as the record was updated so quickly. I then set the refresh rate of the database to 1 sec for both ODBC updates and normal updates, this made sure the database was then updated within 1 sec, thus solving the problem for 95% of calls. I also set the default record locking to editor locking, so that even if 2 ports were being used for the same record, only 1 updated the database.