# Access/ADO.NET data inconsistency (caching?)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I'm connecting from VB.NET 2013 to Access (System.Data.Odbc library, .accdb database format). The first query returns 16 rows and the second query returns 0. Is there some sort of caching problem going on here? Earlier in the code, I do clear out the table and insert the 16 records in.

This returns "16 0"

```
Dim dt1 As New DataTable, dt2 As New DataTable
Dim cnn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & db & ";")
Dim da1 As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sys_Current_Cells] WHERE [Inforce Table ID] > -9999", cnn)
Dim da2 As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sys_Current_Cells] WHERE 1 = 1", cnn)
da1.Fill(dt1)
da2.Fill(dt2)
Debug.Print(dt1.Rows.Count & " " & dt2.Rows.Count)
```

Comment: Have you tried it with vanilla code without that "helper"?

Comment: That doesn't help. I cleaned up the post to remove the helper code.

Comment: Restarting my computer didn't do anything. Compact and repair gets me standard functionality, until I clear and insert the rows.

Comment: I tried this against a ms-access table (changed field names and table name), got the same row count. With that there is something else going on but not with the code presented.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17063542/2144390) to be of interest. In any case, a [mcve] of your issue would certainly help, especially given the comment from @KarenPayne above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here. Is there a way to upload a database, or should I populate the database from code?

Comment: That's a little different behavior than what I was experiencing. The issue seems to be that the data is populated with a INSERT statement from an external database (IN keyword). Pulling the results to a datatable then inserting them manually seems to fix this issue and other issues.