# ODBC behaving asynchronously?

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

I'm finding that when I use an OdbcConnection to update a Jet SQL database, the c# code completes quickly, but the database isn't updated for several hundred milliseconds.  So when I read the database immediately after code-completion of the line that's updating it, I'm reading old data.

After one particular UPDATE, I'm immediately re-loading a grid and it's showing unchanged data unless I pause.
The SQL command is fairly straightforward, like:
*UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 3 WHERE ID = 3000*

```
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))

{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OdbcCommand(SQLText, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters = SQLParams;
        int dummy = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
    }
}
```

If I un-comment the Sleep line, updated data is read afterwards, otherwise old data is read.

I'm running with a local DB, so it's not that other users are keeping the DB busy.

Even if the application terminates after updating and a different application reads the data immediately, the different application is reading old data.  This makes me think that it's something inherent in ODBC functionality (rather than the OdbcConnection itself) that is not immediately processing the SQL.

Can I get the SQL to be processed immediately?

Alternatively, can I interrogate the ODBC to find when processing has completed?

Comment: This may be a sharing issue.  How are you trying to read back data?  The using block is disposing the command and connection.  Until the connection is disposed the file is locked by Windows so you may get a copy of the data in Read Only Mode.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the idea. I'm reading data back through a different OdbcConnection or from a different exe after the exe that's updating has closed.  In both cases, I'm finding stale data.

I tried adding a Dispose & new OdbcConnection (on the connection that's reading in the same exe) after the UPDATE, but still the issue persists.

Of course, reading from a different exe after the exe that's updating has closed means that everything in the updating exe is closed & disposed before stale data is still read.

Comment: You need to check if the dummy value is zero if you have a primary key.  A zero when updating indicates the key is not in the database and you have to do an insert.  When you do an insert and dummy is a zero the key is already in the database and you need to do an update.

Comment: @jdweng the dummy value is 1 for the UPDATE (the number of records reported as having been updated).  And the record is indeed getting updated eventually, it's just not completed when ExecuteNonQuery finishes, it's 500ms - 800ms later

Comment: I've been using JET with ODBC for a long time and never seen this type of results.  The only issues I've seen is when sharing is occurring.  JET is not meant for sharing (or parallel processing).  What type of database are you using (extension)?  Where is the FILE located?  How large if the FILE?  If you are getting a dummy value of 1 then the data was written.  So either something else changed the value or you are not reading from the same location.  I've also seen cases where the database was corrupted and data was not save properly. With JET a database can get badly fragmented or corrupted.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using a 7.5MB Access 2000 MDB file on my local hard drive, and nothing else is accessing the DB at the time of the UPDATE.  Only 12 records in the table being updated.  I defragmented (Compact & Repair) and get the same results.  Yes, the data does get written, but only a few hundred ms after ExecuteNonQuery completes...

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: I suspect you have a locking issue.  Read the "Lock Promotion" section at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/saving-changes-require-exclusive-lock  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/lock-files-introduction

Comment: I think you need an update to remove the locks after writing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/odbc/recordset-locking-records-odbc?view=msvc-160

Comment: related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063542/2144390 - It refers to OleDb but also applies to ODBC.

Comment: @jdweng re: "JET is not meant for sharing" - Sorry, but that is simply not true.

Comment: @GordThompson : You are wrong.  JET just reads a file and doesn't have any locking and in windows two people cannot open a file and both have write permission.

Comment: @jdweng re: "in windows two people cannot open a file and both have write permission" - [Really?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7mX.png)

Comment: @GordThompson : do not change my words.

Comment: @jdweng re: "do not change my words" - I didn't. I copied your words exactly from your [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987075/odbc-behaving-asynchronously?noredirect=1#comment114995761_64987075).

Answer (score 3):

Just to confirm that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063542/2144390) does indeed also hold true for ODBC, this code …

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace odbcConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = 
                  @"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
                + @"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb";
            using (var con1 = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            using (var con2 = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con1.Open();
                con2.Open();
                using (var cmd1 = new OdbcCommand())
                using (var cmd2 = new OdbcCommand())
                {
                    cmd1.Connection = con1;
                    cmd2.Connection = con2;

                    var tableName = "so64987075";
                    var selectCommand = $"SELECT MyField FROM {tableName} WHERE ID = 3000";
                    cmd1.CommandText = selectCommand;
                    int startValue = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - con1 - MyField = {startValue}");
                    cmd1.CommandText = $"UPDATE {tableName} SET MyField = MyField + 1 WHERE ID = 3000";
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - con1 - UPDATE completed.");
                    //con1.Close();

                    cmd2.CommandText = selectCommand;
                    int newValue = -1;
                    do
                    {
                        newValue = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - con2 - MyField = {newValue}");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    } while (newValue == startValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

… produces the following console output:

```
2020-11-27 12:05:24 - con1 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:24 - con1 - UPDATE completed.
2020-11-27 12:05:24 - con2 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:25 - con2 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:26 - con2 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:27 - con2 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:28 - con2 - MyField = 8
2020-11-27 12:05:29 - con2 - MyField = 9
```

> Can I get the SQL to be processed immediately?

Yes, by closing the connection. Uncommenting the `//con1.Close();` line above produces

```
2020-11-27 12:07:19 - con1 - MyField = 9
2020-11-27 12:07:19 - con1 - UPDATE completed.
2020-11-27 12:07:19 - con2 - MyField = 10
```

Comment: While that does improve things somewhat, it's still not behaving properly.  After adding an explicit Close(), I frequently read fresh data afterwards, but not always.

Comment: I tried a test similar to the above while a separate ODBC process was updating the same record once per second and with the explicit `con1.Close()` enabled con2 never had to wait more than 3 ms before seeing the updated value. (The UPDATE on con1 sometimes had to wait for ~1 second before completing, but that didn't affect the time con2 had to wait to see the results.) Apparently there's something else going on in your environment that I haven't accounted for. Inadvertently having ODBC tracing enabled can slow things down, but the effect would be more consistent.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be an ASP.NET application, would it?

Comment: No, it's a Windows desktop application, no tracing enabled.  I'm seeing the issue in 2 scenarios.  1: Update a record and immediately load a grid that contains that record.  2: Insert into a table and the application closes.  Another application takes over and can't immediately see the inserted data.  I may have no choice but to poll the data and wait till changes have taken effect before considering it complete.

Answer (score 0):

Tossing an idea out -- would closing the connection after the using statement or nesting a using statement with outer using statement for the connection do anything?  I am thinking the issue might be related to unmanaged resources or the dispose implementation might trigger some sort of forced update.

Comment: I've tried closing & reopening all connections with no improvement.  In fact, even the entire application terminating and a different application reading quickly suffers from the same problem.  This makes me think that it's nothing to do with the c# code, and and that it's something inherent in the ODBC connection itself.